# How to make $ vim cmd jump to last character(Visual mode), but not CR-LF in dos file?

Tags: vim

In dos file(**windows file**), in vim **Visual mode**, when I execute the **'$'** command, **it jumps to the CR-LF character**, but not the last visible character. In many cases, I just want to yank the visible line, not including the CR-LF character. 
Though I can make a left-movement after cursor jumps to the CR-LF character, it is still somekind troublesome...

Does anyone has some good tips about this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why not staying out of visual mode and just use `y$`?

Comment: @Lieven Keersmaekers, oh, your command is great! Sorry, I'm new to vim, I just thought to yank the characters, I need to enter into visual mode first. Thank you very much!

Comment: You are welcome. As you get more proficient with vim, you'll notice you don't get into visual mode as much as you used to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer to your question stricly, you can add this to your `vimrc`:

```
vnoremap $ $h
```

The first part of the command can be decomposed in 3 part:

- `map` allows to map a key to make it act as if you were hitting other keys.
- `v` indicates that this mapping is only effective in visual mode
- `nore` indicates that the mapping is not recursive (i.e. if you use a key you mapped in another mapping vim will see it as its original value and not as a mapped key, which is generally better for stability)

With this mapping, when you hit `$` in visual mode Vim will behave as if you had hit `$h` which is going to CRLF and one left, so the last character of the line. (For more details see [`:h mapping`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/map.html#mapping)).

That being said, @Lieven comment is very true the more you use vim the less you'll use visual mode.

Comment: great thanks for such detailed explanation! I will keep moving on the vim learning road. ^_^